# Autorunning Plex command In Ubuntu Unity on Chromebook?

Tags: unity, chromebook, plex, autorun, crouton

I have managed to get the Plex Media Server running on my Chromebook via Crouton and Unity.

The only thing is that it won't load unless I run the command `sudo su -c /usr/sbin/start_pms plex`

Is there an easy way to run this automatically when I boot into Crouton? This would make my life alot easier.

Thanks guys,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run scripts on start up?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Comment: Whether you use `upstart`, `/etc/crontab` or `/etc/rc.local`, skip the `sudo su -c` - all three run as root. You shouldn't have to do `su -c` either - `sudo /usr/bin/...` would be just fine.

Comment: There seems to be so many ways to do this but I can't do any, i've made a .conf file with /usr/sbin/start_pms plex inside and i've added it via the menu to Startup applications but it doesn't do anything. It won't let me move the file to etc/init telling me permissions denied.

Comment: There were so many ways that you combined them all, eh? Pick one and stick with it. At the moment what you did corresponds to three different ways.

Comment: Sorry Muru, i'm really not good with Linux :-( Any advice you can give me is very greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried all this but it still didn't work after a reboot;https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByUXeTtKbYTZVmJBOG5FWXQ0WlU/edit?usp=docslist_api any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't since I have no idea what Plex is. What does the `/var/log/upstart/startplex.log` file contain?

Comment: That folder is empty, no files in it at all? Would there be hidden files in there? Do I have to install Upstart?

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, I'd suggest using upstart. To create an upstart job, create a file called `startplex.conf` in `/etc/init/`, containing:

```
start on startup
task
exec /usr/sbin/start_pms plex
```

To do this in one command:

```
sudo tee /etc/init/startplex.conf <<EOF
start on startup
task
exec /usr/sbin/start_pms plex
EOF
```